# $||x||\leqslant 1$, the function is limited proof

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Proposition:** Let $A\in Hom(X,Y)$(Hom(X,Y) is the vector space of linear apllications from $X$ to $Y$).
> Let $||A||=\sup_{x\subset X:||x||\leqslant 1} ||Ax||=\sup_{x\subset X,||x||= 1} ||Ax||=\inf\{M\in\mathbb{R}_+:||Ax||\leqslant M||x||\forall x\in X\}$.
>
> Prove that if $A$ is continuous in $0$ then $A$ is limited.

**Proof**:Suppose that $A$ is continuous in $0$. Let $\delta>0$ such as $||Ax||\leqslant 1$, if ||x||\leqslant\delta. Therefore if $||x||\leqslant 1$, $Ax=A(\delta\frac{x}{||x||})\frac{||x||}{\delta}\leqslant\frac{1}{\delta}$. So $A$ is limited, according to the norm.

**Question:**

**1)** I cannot see why is $A(\delta\frac{x}{||x||})\frac{||x||}{\delta}\leqslant\frac{1}{\delta}$ true? Can someone include some extra steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly i don't understand the meaning of $Ax\leq \frac{1}{\delta}$. $Ax=z \in Y$, so how can you compare that to the number $\delta$? The thing that you can compare to $\delta$ is the norm of $Ax=z$.
$\left\| A\left(\delta \frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\frac{\|x\|}{\delta}\right\|=\left\| A\left(\delta \frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|\frac{\|x\|}{\delta}\leq\left\| A\left(\delta \frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\|\frac{1}{\delta}=\left\| A(y)\right\|\frac{1}{\delta}$. Now $\|y\|=\delta$ so we have that $\|A(y)\|\leq1$. We obtain: $\left\| A\left(\delta \frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\frac{\|x\|}{\delta}\right\|\leq \frac{1}{\delta}$.